# SQL multiple rows calculate

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server and I am trying to calculate if a number is bigger than a selected row, but only if the rows that exist are greater than 1.

I've looked online and looked into Union, Intersect and Exist but cannot see a way to do it and of course I may have to program the calculation in C++ but would rather do it in SQL as it will be faster.

The example is as follows: the table lists a number of horse races and data (needs to sorted by date and time in the selection):

```
Date        Time        Course      OF  Win
-------------------------------------------
2018-10-16  15:45:00    Huntingdon  5   LC        
2018-10-16  15:45:00    Huntingdon  3   W         
2018-10-16  16:10:00    Punchtown   1   LC        
2018-10-16  16:10:00    Punchtown   2   W         
2018-10-16  16:20:00    Huntingdon  3   LC        
2018-10-16  16:20:00    Huntingdon  2   W         
2018-10-16  16:30:00    Hereford    5   W         
2018-10-16  16:30:00    Hereford    4   LC        
2018-10-16  16:45:00    Punchtown   3   W
```

In the above data I wouldn't be interested in the last record as only one for that date and time exists. From the other four races I would like to calculate how many races that have a 'W', have a 'OF' value greater than the 'LC' line.  The output would count how many races have this condition.

A further complication is there may be more than two records for that date and time. I've looked at this for two days now without success so just before I do program it I thought I'd ask.

SG

Comment: It would be helpful if you shared more sample data to cover your scenarios AND your desired results. It's unclear what *"If it is then count all records that have this outcome for their date and time."* means. How would that be outputted in the same result set as the first record?

Comment: Where's your query???

Comment: In the two research days, did you come across Row_Number?
Partitioning by Date and Time might be what you're looking for...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I have some questions: 1) do you have only W and LC row types? 2) can you have many W per one date/time and the same question for LC type rows? 3) if you can have several W-s and LC-s - which are considered in comparing W row number > LC row(s) number?

Comment: Just added more detail and checking the Row_Number function.  In answer to Robert Lujo,

Comment: Just added more detail and checking the Row_Number function.  In answer to Robert Lujo 1.)  Only W rows but there could be LC,LA,LR in the same race.  2.)  Only one W per date/time 3.) All the L types.

Comment: I'd start with a group by on date/course. But it gets a lot harder to find the 'w' and compare it with the last 'lost'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your sample data, the following should do the trick...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestData', 'U') IS NULL 
BEGIN   -- DROP TABLE #TestData;
    CREATE TABLE #TestData (
        [Date] DATE NOT NULL,
        [Time] TIME(0) NOT NULL,
        Course VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
        [OF] INT NOT NULL,
        Win CHAR(2) NOT NULL 
        );

    INSERT #TestData (Date, Time, Course, [OF], Win)
    VALUES
    ('2018-10-16', '15:45:00', 'Huntingdon', 5, 'LC'),       
    ('2018-10-16', '15:45:00', 'Huntingdon', 3, 'W'),       
    ('2018-10-16', '16:10:00', 'Punchtown ', 1, 'LC'),       
    ('2018-10-16', '16:10:00', 'Punchtown ', 2, 'W'),       
    ('2018-10-16', '16:20:00', 'Huntingdon', 3, 'LC'),       
    ('2018-10-16', '16:20:00', 'Huntingdon', 2, 'W'),       
    ('2018-10-16', '16:30:00', 'Hereford  ', 5, 'W'),       
    ('2018-10-16', '16:30:00', 'Hereford  ', 4, 'LC'),       
    ('2018-10-16', '16:45:00', 'Punchtown ', 3, 'W')
END;

--========================================================

WITH
    cte_LagVal AS (
        SELECT 
            td.Date,
            td.Time,
            td.Course,
            td.[OF],
            td.Win,
            LC_OF = LAG(td.[OF], 1) OVER (PARTITION BY td.Date, td.Time, td.Course ORDER BY td.Win)
        FROM
            #TestData td
        )
SELECT 
    lv.Date,
    lv.Time,
    lv.Course,
    lv.[OF],
    lv.Win,
    lv.LC_OF
FROM
    cte_LagVal lv
WHERE 
    lv.LC_OF IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers.

Comment: No problem. Glad to help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (I did not test it):

```
--Outer query will join the subquery. Needed to figure out the win 
select time, course, of, win
from table t1 
inner join
   -- subquery to get the last OF for each time, course.
   (select time, course, max(OF) maxof
    from table t2
    group by time, course) as t2
on t1.time = t2.time, t1.course = t2.course, t1.of = t2.maxof
where win = 'lc' -- If there's only a win, this will show nothing.
```